# how to drag and drop generated image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, image

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add_btn').click(function() {  
    var src$ = $('#img_loc').val();
    $('<img>').attr({
        src: src$,
        class: 'canDrag'}).appendTo($('#work_area'));
    });

    $('.canDrag').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('dragMe');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('dragMe');
        }
    );

    $('.canDrag').draggable();
    $('.dropSpace').droppable({
        accept:'.canDrag'
    });
});
```

The directory path for both jquery and jquery ui are correct, but I'm still not able to drag images with the class `'canDrag'.`Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the initialization code after the image is created.  At present, when you create a new image, it's entirely new and doesn't have your events attached to it.  Try something like this:

```
$('#add_btn').click(function() {  
    var src$ = $('#img_loc').val();
    $('<img>').attr({
        src: src$,
        class: 'canDrag'
    }).appendTo($('#work_area'));

    $('.canDrag').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('dragMe');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('dragMe');
        }
    );

    $('.canDrag').draggable();
    $('.dropSpace').droppable({
        accept:'.canDrag'
    });
});
```

Comment: @Joseph--initializing the draggable method was the issue. thanks for the help!